# Is the relation $x \geq 2y$ transitive?

Tags: relations

I am trying to understand if the relation $x \geq 2y$ is transitive.  I think the answer is no for the following reasons.  Can someone please let me know if I am correct or incorrect.  If incorrect, why am I incorrect.

Definition of transitive: If $\left ( x,y \right )$ are elements of the relation, and $\left ( y,z \right )$ are elements of the relation, then this implies that $\left ( x,z \right )$ are elements of the relation.

Here is a counter example: $\left ( 4,2 \right )$ are elements of the relation because $4 \geq 2\times 2$.  $\left ( 2,1 \right )$ are also elements of the relation because $2 \geq 2\times 1$.  But, $\left ( 4,1 \right )$ are not elements of the relation because $4$ is not greater than or equal to $2 * 1$.

Comment: But 4 *is* greater than or equal to $2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: At the very end of the question you claim that $4$ *isn't* greater than (or equal to) $2$. Do you see something wrong with this?

Comment: Ok.  Now I feel stupid.  I guess it's a case where I'm not seeing the forest through all the trees.  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\ge2y\land y\ge2z\implies x\ge2y\land 2y\ge4z\implies x\ge 4z\implies x\ge2z.$$

**Update**:
The last implication requires $z\ge0$.

Comment: This assumes, of course, that $x,y,z \geq 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: no, why ?

Comment: Take $x = -3$, $z = -1$. We have $x \geq 4z$, but not $x \geq 2z$.

Comment: Yep, stupid me, we need $4z\ge2z$. (But $x$ and $y$ can be negative.)

Comment: @Crostul your comment is good!  Use `\neg` rather than `\not`.

Answer (score 1):

What set is your relation defined on?
If it's for positive numbers, then it is transitive, as Yves Daoust showed.

If the numbers can be negative, we could have:
$$x = -3, y =-\frac{7}{4}, z = -1$$
Then $x = -3 \geq-3.5 =2y$, $y =-\frac{7}{4}  \geq -2 = 2z$, but $x = -3 < -2 = 2z$.

Comment: It only occurs because of $z<0$.

Comment: It seems to work if $x$ is non-negative. Suppose $x\geq 0$, and we have that $x\geq 2y$ and $y\geq 2z$, and $z < 0$. Then $x \geq 0 > 2z$.

Comment: The original problem I was working on was defined on the naturals but I am very appreciative that you showed how the relation is not transitive if it includes negative numbers.

Comment: @Santeri: the transitivity can only be falsified when $z<0$, irrespective of the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I agree. I thought you meant 'if and only if' with your first comment. It's a necessary but not sufficient condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is not transitive, since it fails to be transitive when you work with negative numbers. As an example,
$$-4 \ge 2 \cdot (-2) \mbox{  and } -2 \ge 2 \cdot (-1)$$
but
$$-4 \ge 2 \cdot (-1) \mbox{ is false}$$